# Need to hide all elements of an svg except for the ones selected from a list javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I've created a list of operators to show up on a map to map their pipelines. I want to be able to only hide all the pipelines that haven't been checked from the list. So if one operator is checked then show only that one operators pipelines on the map. Right now it's hiding everything because of the selectAll, but I've tried a few other options and nothing seems to work. It either hides them all or none.
JS:

```
    if($("#pipeExclusion").val() == 1 ){
       map.svg.selectAll(".pipe").style("visibility", "hidden");
    } else if($("#pipeExclusion").val() == 0){
       map.svg.selectAll(".pipe").style("visibility", "visible");
    }
```

Here is where I pull in all the pipelines

```
        if(map.filters.showPipes){
        map.svg.selectAll(".pipe")
            .data(topojson.feature(pipeData, pipeData.objects.ngpipes).features).enter().append("path")
            .attr("class", function(d){return "pipe test p" + pipeOperators.indexOf(d.properties.name);})
            .attr("d", map.svgPath); //map.svgPath
        } 

        for(i=0;i<pipeOperators.length;i++){
        if(map.filters.showPipes == 1){
            $("#pipeOperatorsList").append("<li><input type='checkbox' class='pipeOperator' value=p" + pipeOperators.indexOf(pipeOperators[i]) + "> " + pipeOperators[i] + "</li>");
           }
        }
```

I tried to add an && into the top if to check the status of the class for the operators that are in the list but it doesn't work because it won't hide any when I do that. Any tips?

Comment: Where's your list of operators? Could I see the html? (*Hint:* Why don't you add classes to specify which ones to [hide/display]?)

Comment: @JefréN. I edited my question and added how I'm pulling the operators in. They all have the same class name, but on the map each pipeline has it's own class name, such as p0,p1,p2.. and so on like that. I'm just not sure how to make it see if one operator is checked then hide all other pipelines except the one that's checked.

Comment: Thanks. Can I assume that operators will never default to being checked?

Comment: @JefréN. I got it figured out. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my answer.. had to create a new click function

```
        $(".pipeOperator").click(function(){
        if(this.checked == true){
            console.log("." + this.value);
            //$("." + this.value).style("visibility", "visible");
            map.svg.selectAll("." + this.value).style("visibility", "visible");
        }
        if(this.checked == false){
            console.log("." + this.value);
            //$("." + this.value).style("visibility", "hidden");
            map.svg.selectAll("." + this.value).style("visibility", "hidden");
        }
    });
```